# Forgot password in aspnet identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have been following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity%20to%20implement%20the%20forgot%20password%20functionality)

The article doesn't appear to be complete.

This is the web API I'd create to generate the forgot password link as per the article.

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("**ResetPassword**", "Account", 
    new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
    "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");        
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

As we can see the ResetPassword is the URL action that is supposed to be invoked when the link is clicked in our inbox. However the article doesn't give a method definition for ResetPassword API.

Comment: Step 1) Create a new ASP.NET project and select Authentication > local users. Step 2) Copy the code you want to your project. Done

Comment: Camilo that might indeed help out. However no resources on the internet that would talk about this eh ?

Comment: Not sure about that, but the code is a copy-paste from the auto-generated code. Also, if you are just starting out, you should start with ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET MVC 5 won't last long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there must be ResetPassword method inside your controller as an action method.

```
  //
  // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
  {
     return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
  }

  //
  // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
  {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        return View(model);
     }

     var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
     if (user == null)
     {
        // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
        return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
     }
     var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
        return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
     }
     AddErrors(result);
     return View();
  }
```

Source: [Link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-5-with-2FA-email-8f26d952)

Comment: This looks promising. I would implement the idea in a bit